# Best answer to my question actually is a wrong answer

Tags: questions, answers, discussion

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41097194/4960953) question about MATLAB code. If you now usually vectorized code in MATLAB works faster than code using `for` loops. So actually my question was to **achieve vectorized code**.

But the answer used `for` loops give me the fastest result!
So I am a little confused which answer I have to accept, because really I asked about vectorized code not fastest!

One more moment - there can be possibility of my inefficient implementation of some of answers in vectorized form, so my calculation of time can be not really accurate.

Comment: Basically it's up to you; what I'd do is pick the answer I feel is closest to my requirement, then provide a nice comment under the other explaining why I picked the other answer, and what is good about this one.

Comment: Don't overthink about it, pick the one you feel most helped you with the question you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked your question on the premise that vectorized code was supposedly faster than using for loops. One of the answers then demonstrated that using for loops was in fact faster in your use case..

So which answer you accept depends on what you make of this revelation. If what you're really interested in is the most optimized solution, then go ahead and accept the for loop answer. I wouldn't call it a wrong answer. It would be wrong if it showed the opposite: for loops actually being slower than vectorization. Then I'd wonder just what the point was in that answer being posted, at all.

If you can't decide, then you don't have to accept any of the answers. If someone comes along and tries to make you (which they shouldn't be doing), refer them to your meta question and/or explain to them why you abstained from picking an accepted answer.

Comment: The next logical question for you to ask, of course, is ***why*** this code using for loops is faster than vectorized code. (I don't know beans about MATLAB, but I suspect, if there is any sort of optimizing compiler involved, that the code is being auto-vectorized, and the compiler does a better job with simple for loops than when you try to outsmart it.) @mikhail

Comment: Indeed; that would make an excellent follow-up question.